# Knockout js binding on properties of nullable objects

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a knockout.js page which loads data from an API and uses the knockout mapping plugin to turn the data into a parameter on the ViewModel.

The data contains nested objects e.g.

```
[{
    id: 1,
    targetField: {
        id: 132,
        name: 'Field ABC',
        ...
    },
    conditionalOperator: {
        id: 8,
        display: 'Less Than'
    },
    conditionalValue:13
},
...
]
```

Loaded into the page view model

```
var PageViewModel = function() {
    ...
    this.allConditionLogic = ko.observableArray();
}

var pageViewModel = new PageViewModel();

$.get('api/...')
    .done(function(data) {
        pageViewModel.allConditionLogic(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
    });
```

The html contains bindings to the objects

```
<div data-bind="foreach: allConditionLogic">
    <p>Field id <span data-bind="text: targetField().id"></span> <span data-bind="text: conditionalOperator().display"></span> <span data-bind="text: conditionalValue"></span></p>
</div>
```

This however errors as before the ajax call has returned, `targetField` and `conditionalOperator` are `null`.

It is possible to use extra `span` elements and the `with` binding which doesn't create the internal html if the bound object doesn't exist - e.g.

```
<p>Field id <span data-bind="with: targetField"><span data-bind="text: id"></span> <span data-bind="with: conditionalOperator"><span data-bind="text: display"></span></span> <span data-bind="text: conditionalValue"></span></p>
```

however this seams somewhat overkill.  I could define a blank object in `allConditionLogic` with the correct fields, but that requires a lot more typing and needs updating if the API changes.

Is there a better way of getting this to work?

Comment: Does it really throw an error though? If `allConditionLogic` is an empty array, knockout will not apply any bindings to the `<p>` template inside.

Comment: Good point, I'll have a look as to why - I probably simplified the example too much...

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution could be to create a knockout observable variable and set it to `false` until you have the data returned by the API. Then wrap your `div` with that observable inside a `ko if:` binding -

```
var PageViewModel = function() {
this.allConditionLogic = ko.observableArray();
//Set it to false initially
this.hasAPIreturnedData = ko.observableArray(false);
}

var pageViewModel = new PageViewModel();

$.get('api/...')
    .done(function(data) {
        pageViewModel.allConditionLogic(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
        //make it true after data is returned and is transformed
        pageViewModel.hasAPIreturnedData(true);
    });


<!--ko if: hasAPIreturnedData -->
<div data-bind="foreach: allConditionLogic">
    <p>Field id <span data-bind="text: targetField().id"></span> <span data-bind="text: conditionalOperator().display"></span> <span data-bind="text: conditionalValue"></span></p>
</div>
<!--/ko-->
```

There could be more elegant ways of handling this but that depends on a lot of things. As I said, this is the simplest solution I could think of :)